# Folder Last Modified Date Discrepancy in Windows Explorer due to Subfolder Changes

Tags: windows, explorer, ntfs, last-modified

I am aware there are familiar threads to this problem, but i think this is a more direct approach.

```
root
└── A/
    └── B/
        └── asdf.txt (content modified)
```

Modifying "asdf.txt" correctly updates the last modified date of folder "B", but the change is not reflected in the last modified date of folder "A" when seen from its parent ("root") directory.

1.) Is there a method or a setting within Windows Explorer that ensures the last modified date of a parent folder synchronizes with changes in its subfolders, maintaining accurate modification timestamps throughout the directory tree?

2.) Are there alternative approaches or third-party tools that can achieve this synchronization of last modified dates for folder structures in Windows?

3.) Is this a general NTFS problem?

Comment: A was not modified. Before your change to asdf.txt, A had one subitem (B). After your change, it still has one subitem. In general, propagating changes up the tree results in a very high rate of writes, because every change anywhere on the drive would force an update of the root directory's last-modified timestamp. (It would also be a potential information disclosure security vulnerability, since it lets you see that there is activity in a part of the drive you wouldn't normally have access to.)

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice to have at least the option to enable this out of the box.